# How can I programmatically access Dark mode colors when in light mode and vice versa in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, ios-darkmode

An `accentColor` can have an "Any Appearance" color and a "Dark Appearance" color. Lets say, I'm in light mode, how can I access the dark mode color programmatically without manually setting the color mode to dark mode?

Answer (score 2):

You need to resolve your named color to trait collection of dark style, like

```
.background(
   Color(UIColor(named: "testColor")?.resolvedColor(with: 
      UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)) ?? UIColor.darkText)
)
```

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

*Note: tune to your color name and any default color to unwrap optional*

Comment: Looks good in SO, but when I try it, I get `Value of type 'Color' has no member 'resolvedColor'` when I do the following: `import SwiftUI
extension Color {
    func opposite(scheme: ColorScheme) -> Color {
        resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark))
    }
}`

Comment: The `resolvedColor` is a method of `UIColor`, not `Color`, but `Color` can be created with `UIColor`, as shown.