# How to programmatically get asset catalog color variants from in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, color-scheme

I have a color asset catalog in Xcode that defines a set of colors in both light ("Any") and dark ("Dark") variants. For example:

[image: Picture of asset catalog color]

I would like to programmatically enumerate the different colors, meaning, I'd like to get the color (`Color("hkMagenta")`) in both variants. Just getting it by name returns the "Any" variant.

How can I get the dark variant?

I had thought this would work:

```
ColorManager.hkMagenta.environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
```

Unfortunately, no-go.

> Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected element type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'Color')

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950858/12299030?

Comment: Thanks for the references – exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I programmatically access Dark mode colors when in light mode and vice versa in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949181/how-can-i-programmatically-access-dark-mode-colors-when-in-light-mode-and-vice-v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Asperi for pointing out https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950858/12299030.

TL;DR is, you can get the light and dark variants using `UIColor.resolvedColor()` like so:

```
let c = Color(UIColor(named: "hkMagenta")!.resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)))
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: Preview Image]

You can specify .colorScheme for each view depending upon your needs like

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            Text("Light Magenta color from asset")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color("hkMagenta"))
                .environment(\.colorScheme, .light) //ColoScheme
            
            Text("Dark Magenta color from asset")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color("hkMagenta"))
                .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark) //ColoScheme
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the post, but this doesn't actually answer my question. Assigning the attribute using `.environment` and `colorScheme` is fine, but I'm specifically trying to assign the `Color` value to a variable. (See above for another post that answers my original question).

Comment: Ok, its better that you got right answer.